# AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute '_name_'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying String formatting-Long String 'replacement field names'. But I am getting an 'Attribute error'.

I have searched about the error but there are no similar answers.

```
import math

tmpl="This {mod._name_} module defines the value of pie as  {mod.pi}"

print(tmpl.format(mod=math))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:/Python/Beginning Python/Ch-3/2String-Long version.py", line 14, in
>
> print(tmpl.format(mod=math))
>
> AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute '*name*'

I expect that this error should not occur.

Comment: Try `__name__`, not `_name_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two underscores before and after the `__name__` attribute.

```
tmpl="This {mod.__name__} module defines the value of pie as  {mod.pi}"
```